# Counter for two binary strings C++

Tags: string, count, binary

I am trying to count two binary numbers from string. The maximum number of counting digits have to be 253. Short numbers works, but when I add there some longer numbers, the output is wrong. The example of bad result is "10100101010000111111" with "000011010110000101100010010011101010001101011100000000111000000000001000100101101111101000111001000101011010010111000110".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

bool isBinary(string b1,string b2);

int main()
{
string b1,b2;
long binary1,binary2;
int i = 0, remainder = 0, sum[254];

cout<<"Get two binary numbers:"<<endl;
cin>>b1>>b2;
binary1=atol(b1.c_str());
binary2=atol(b2.c_str());
if(isBinary(b1,b2)==true){
    while (binary1 != 0 || binary2 != 0){

    sum[i++] =(binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) % 2;
    remainder =(binary1 % 10 + binary2 % 10 + remainder) / 2;
    binary1 = binary1 / 10;
    binary2 = binary2 / 10;
    }

    if (remainder != 0){
    sum[i++] = remainder;
    }
    --i;
    cout<<"Result: ";

    while (i >= 0){
    cout<<sum[i--];
    }
    cout<<endl;

}else cout<<"Wrong input"<<endl;

return 0;
}

   bool isBinary(string b1,string b2){
    bool rozhodnuti1,rozhodnuti2;

     for (int i = 0; i < b1.length();i++) {
       if (b1[i]!='0' && b1[i]!='1') {
        rozhodnuti1=false;
        break;
    }else rozhodnuti1=true;
}

for (int k = 0; k < b2.length();k++) {
    if (b2[k]!='0' && b2[k]!='1') {
        rozhodnuti2=false;
        break;
    }else rozhodnuti2=true;
}

 if(rozhodnuti1==false || rozhodnuti2==false){ return false;}
 else{ return true;}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems might be here: `sum[i++]`
This expression, as it is, first returns the value of `i` and then increases it by one.

Did you do it on purporse?
Change it to `++i`.

It'd help if you could also post the "bad" output, so that we can try to move backward through the code starting from it.

---

### EDIT 2015-11-7_17:10

Just to be sure everything was correct, I've added a `cout` to check what `binary1` and `binary2` contain after you assing them the result of the `atol` function: they contain the integer numbers `547284487` and `18333230`, which obviously dont represent the correct binary-to-integer transposition of the two `01` strings you presented in your post.
Probably they somehow exceed the capacity of `atol`.

Also, the result of your "math" operations bring to an even stranger result, which is `6011111101`, which obviously doesnt make any sense.

What do you mean, exactly, when you say you want to `count` these two numbers? Maybe you want to make a sum? I guess that's it.
But then, again, what you got there is two signed integer numbers and not two binaries, which means those `%10` and `%2` operations are (probably) misused.

---

### EDIT 2015-11-07_17:20

I've tried to use your program with small binary strings and it actually works; with small binary strings.
It's a fact(?), at this point, that `atol` cant handle numerical strings that long.

My suggestion: use `char` arrays instead of strings and replace `0` and `1` characters with numerical values (`if (bin1[i]){bin1[i]=1;}else{bin1[i]=0}`) with which you'll be able to perform all the math operations you want (you've already written a working `sum` function, after all).

Once done with the math, you can just convert the `char` array back to actual characters for `0` and `1` and `cout` it on the screen.

---

### EDIT 2015-11-07_17:30

Tested `atol` on my own: it correctly converts only strings that are up to 10 characters long.
Anything beyond the 10th character makes the function go crazy.